# Joint PDF of two random variables in a triangle more detail

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, self-learning

> Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have a joint PDF which is uniform
> over the triangle with vertices at $(0, 0), (0, 1 )$ and $(1, 0)$.

> Find the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$.

[from](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703272/joint-pdf-of-two-random-variables-in-a-triangle)

Someone answered

> $$S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: 0\le x\le 1, \; 0\le y\le 1-x\}$$

my drawing:

[image]

**Problem 1**: I don't know why he represent $y$ as $1-x$, instead of just $0\leq y \leq 1$. To my understanding, $x,y$ can be any point $0\leq x,y \leq 1$. I know the longest side of triangle is $x+y=1$, but dont know what's the relationship.

**Problem 2**: Also, why someone call it joint PDF, someone call it multivaible PDF, which one is correct?

Comment: you should try drawing the given triangle in the xy plane before asking such a question. As for "joint pdf" that's often used in the multivariable case when there are two variables.

Comment: @coffeemath, after drawing still dont understand..

Comment: "uniform over" means the pdf is a constant for any point in the triangle, and that probabilities for subsets of the triangle are computed as that constant multiplied by the area of the subset. Now the triangle has three sides: a segment from (0,0) to (0,1), another from (0,0) to (1,0), and the third from (0,1) to (1,0). If you really drew it correctly, you would know why e.g. the point (1,1) is *not* included, however your description includes this point.

Comment: In the $xy$ plane, the points which are inside the hatched half-square have their coordinates characterized by $x+y \le 1, x \ge 0, y\ge 0$. Besides, as the volume under the pdf must be $1$, the pdf has constant value $f(x,y)=2$ in order to have $2 \times 1/2 = 1$.

Comment: Ohh, we cannot have event that is x=1 and y=1 at the same time, all the event have to falls into the hatched half-square, thus we need give x,y such constrain.

Comment: Now that your diagram is there (it wasn't before) it's clear your confusion comes from thinking the given triangle has thickness 2 and is part of 3-d space. No. The triangle is in the x-y plane only. What your figure shows is the *graph* of the pdf. It then has three coordinates (x,y,z) for any point over the base triangle in the plane z=0 and under plane z=2.